# Redirect non-www to www using DNS Zone Editor?

Tags: web, dns, http-status-code-404, cname

I've just purchased a new traffic tracking service, which requires my domain (registered at GoDaddy) to have a CNAME record pointing to their servers.

I've done that fine, and it's now working.

However, when typing it in **without** the "www", I get a 404 error page.

My question is, what would I type in the DNS Zone Editor to redirect my "non-www" domain to the "www" domain?

For example, I need my URL to do this…

http://mydomain.com/1234 --> http://www.mydomain.com/1234

Would it be done using an "A name record" or something? Or another way?

I've searched everywhere and can't find a solution that works, so hopefully you can help.

Thanks,
James.

Comment: Update: I got this to work correctly using a reply from GoDaddy's support team. Basically I just needed to use domain forwarding (as karastengal said). Thanks though! :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you just want to send all traffic from `mydomain.com` (known as your 'naked' domain) to `www.mydomain.com` you should be able to use domain forwarding.  In GoDaddy this will be in the Domain Manager under "Domain Information" at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

For those having their servers with AWS and domain registered at Godaddy:

I set up my A record with 2 entries (Host: @ and www) as below to redirect to my server in AWS through the public ip. This catches the URLs with/without the www prefix

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using DNS Manager we cannot redirect our (naked) domain

> (example.com)

to www version

> (www.example.com)

we need web hosting for this purpose. because I try it but results are zero. Using domain hosting it is imposible in my views..
By using Forward domain how can i forward the is here. In screen short. there is a option **Forward to**
My domain is in

> (www.example.com)
>   Version. if i use this option it will redirect to
>    (example.com)
>   According to these settings.

Answer (score 0):

Note my :

```
1] Domain name : GoDaddy
2] Hosted (code) : Heroku (minimum $25/month dyno, dyno is virtual machine, dyno is equivalent to EC2 of AWS)
3] SSL certificate : Bought on GoDaddy  ; and endpoint on Heroku (heroku minimum SSL endpoint on $20/month)
```

These were working :

```
https://www.example.com/  
http://www.example.com/  
www.example.com
```

These were not working :

```
example.com 
http://example.com/
https://example.com/
```

My heroku ssl add on had :

```
www.example.com
example.com
```

Solution:
step 1:in cmd/shell

[image]

[image] [image]

Copy IP address above and use in step 2

step 2:in GoDaddy account

[image]

DONE!!!

Note :
1)remove forwarding if you have to use this solution
2)CNAME - www - sslendpoint

Comment: You can ask me doubts related to this. Feel free.